# Testcafe docker run shows error on specifying global request hook in .testcaferc.js file

Tags: docker, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I get an error **The hook (object) is not of expected type (RequestHook subclass).**

I notice this error when I run the test using the testcafe docker image.

I use the command:

`docker run -v //c/testproject:/mytests -it testcafe/testcafe "chromium:headless:emulation:device=iPhone X" /mytests/testone.js --config-file /mytests/.testcaferc.js`

***I have the following code in my .testcaferc.js file***

```
const { RequestMock} = require("testcafe");

const mock = RequestMock()
.onRequestTo('https://a360cdn.azureedge.net/javascript/a360.consent.default.js')
    .respond(null, 200)

module.exports = {

    hooks: {
            request: [mock]
            },

    browsers:  "chromium:headless:emulation:device=iPhone X",

    skipJsErrors: true,
    skipUncaughtErrors: true,
};
```

***My test file has the following code:***

```
import {Selector} from 'testcafe'

fixture `fixture 1`

test.page(`https://www.chileautos.cl/`)(`First test`, async t => {

await t.expect(Selector(`div.element-id`).exists).ok()

});
```

And my package.json is as below:

```
{
 "scripts": {
       "b": "testcafe ./testone.js"
   
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "testcafe": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

***Note:*** When i run my test without testcafe docker image, the mock request works fine.

For example, I can see the test running good when I run the test using `npm run b`

But if I run the test using the following command:
`docker run -v //c/testproject:/mytests -it testcafe/testcafe "chromium:headless:emulation:device=iPhone X" /mytests/testone.js --config-file /mytests/.testcaferc.js`

I see the following error:

ERROR Cannot prepare tests due to the following error:

The hook (object) is not of expected type (RequestHook subclass).

Type "testcafe -h" for help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mounted folder as a path only for tests. You need to move the configuration file to the root folder or create a custom Docker image that extends the basic TestCafe Docker image and allows specifying `configuration file`.